# Why is the traditional proof of the formula for permutations by the multiplication rule not formal?

Tags: proof-writing, permutations, proof-explanation

The traditional, most common proof of $_nP_n = n!$ is by the multiplication rule:

> There are $n$ choices for the first position, $n-1$ for the second, and so on until there is only one choice for the last position. By the multiplication rule, there are $n(n-1)\dots(2)(1)=n!$ permutations.

Some sources label this proof as "informal," for instance [this LibreTexts textbook](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Combinatorics_and_Discrete_Mathematics/Elementary_Foundations%3A_An_Introduction_to_Topics_in_Discrete_Mathematics_(Sylvestre)/21%3A_Permutations/21.03%3A_Counting_Permutations) and [this ProofWiki page](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Number_of_Permutations). I agree that this proof is informal, but what confused me is the "formal" proof by induction that the former LibreTexts source provided, which is summarized as follows:

> Base case: A single element only has $1!=1$ permutation.
>
> Inductive step: For a set $A$ of $n+1$ elements, remove one element $a$ and put the remaining elements in a set $B$. By the inductive hypothesis, $B$ has $n!$ permutations. For each permutation, insert $a$ in any of the $n+1$ spaces to create $n+1$ permutations of $A$. [The text provides an *example* here to justify the previous statement.] Therefore, there are $(n+1)(n!)=(n+1)!$ permutations of $A$.

Why is the proof by multiplication rule considered informal?

I have thought of a few reasons:

1. It doesn't prove that each permutation created is indeed a **unique** permutation (no permutation appears more than once in the $n!$ counted permutations).
2. It doesn't prove that there aren't more than $n!$ permutations (no permutation has been missed).

My confusion comes from the fact that the "formal" proof above also has the same problems just listed.

Comment: I guess it goes with how we see permutation. If permutation is seen through selecting/choosing, we do not have any formal ways of defining those terms. If the permutation ${}_nP_r$ is seen as the set of all injections from any subset of order $r$ of a set of order $n$ to itself, then the corresponding treatment would be formal.

Comment: Why do you think that the ‘formal proof’ also has the same problems?

Comment: I agree that both proofs are informal. A "formal" proof should use a precise, predefined set of inference rules. Most proofs are informal.

Comment: What makes the first proof truly informal is the "and so on". The rest of it can be directly converted to a formal argument. But the "and so on" requires additional layers to interpret formally - either being converted to an induction argument, or some application of well-ordering. The second proof is not a formalization of the first, but uses a different approach. But it does explicitly contain an induction argument to avoid also requiring "and so on".